# How to remove necessary nodes from a binary tree?

Tags: c, file, data-structures, binary-tree

Good evening forum members.

The following is on the agenda:

1. Read a sequence of coordinates (x, y, z) of spatial points from the file, ordered by distance from the point of origin (develop a separate function for calculating the distance and store this value in the data structure);
2. To bypass use the bottom option from right to left;
3. Extract from the tree all nodes whose z coordinate falls within the specified range zmin ..zmax (I decided to take from 7 to 14) and indicate their number;
4. To completely erase the tree, use the direct (from the root) version of the bypass from left to right;
5. Print the entire tree using a non-recursive function.

Please help with number 3. It is not possible to implement the deletion algorithm according to a given condition. It either does not work at all, or errors arrive (

Thanks in advance to everyone who responds

CODE:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_LEN 8
#define STACK_INIT_SIZE 20

typedef struct Tree {
    int z;
    int viddal;
    struct Tree* left, * right;
} TREE;

typedef struct Stack {
    size_t size, limit;
    TREE** data;
} STACK;

int Distance(FILE* ftxt, int* vid, int* z_cord);
int CreateTreeFromFile(void);
TREE* NewNode(FILE* f, int viddal, int z);
void AddNewNode(TREE* pnew);
void PrintTreeNIZ(TREE* proot);
void iterPostorder(TREE* root);
void OutputTreeStructure(const char* title);
void ShowTree(TREE* proot, int level);
void ShowLevels(void);
int TreeHeight(TREE* proot);
void EraseTree(TREE* proot);
void DeleteSomeNodes(void);
int DeleteNode(TREE* pnew_adr);

TREE* root;

int main(){

    system("chcp 1251");
    if (CreateTreeFromFile() == 0)
        return 0;

    puts("\n Created tree: ");
    PrintTreeNIZ(root);

    OutputTreeStructure("of created tree");

    DeleteSomeNodes();

    OutputTreeStructure("of the new tree");

    EraseTree(root);
    root = NULL;
    puts("\n Tree was deleted from DM\n\n");

    return 0;
}

int Distance(FILE* ftxt, int *vid, int* z_cord) {

    TREE* pel = (TREE*)malloc(sizeof(TREE));

    if (feof(ftxt)) {;
        return NULL;
    }
    else {

        int x, y, z;
        fscanf(ftxt, "%d%d%d", &x, &y, &z);

        *z_cord = z;
        *vid = sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
    }
}

int CreateTreeFromFile()
{
    const char* fname = "Cords_1.txt";
    FILE* fvoc = fopen(fname, "r");

    if (fvoc == NULL) {
        printf("\n\t\tCan`t open file %s...\n", fname);
        return 0;
    }

    TREE* node;
    int viddal, z;
    Distance(fvoc, &viddal, &z);

    while ((node = NewNode(fvoc, viddal, z)) != NULL) {
        AddNewNode(node);
        Distance(fvoc, &viddal, &z);
    }
    fclose(fvoc);
    return 1;
}

TREE* NewNode(FILE* f, int viddal, int z) 
{
    TREE* pel;
    pel = (TREE*)malloc(sizeof(TREE));

    if (feof(f)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    pel->viddal = viddal;
    pel->z = z;

    pel->left = pel->right = NULL;
    return pel;
}


void AddNewNode(TREE* pnew) {

    if (root == NULL) {
        root = pnew;
        return;
    }

    TREE* prnt = root;

    do {
        if (pnew->viddal == prnt->viddal) {
            free(pnew);
            return;
        }

        if (pnew->viddal < prnt->viddal) {
            if (prnt->left == NULL) {
                prnt->left = pnew;
                return;
            }
            else
                prnt = prnt->left;
        }
        else {
            if (prnt->right == NULL) {
                prnt->right = pnew;
                return;
            }
            else
                prnt = prnt->right;
        }
    } while (1);
}

void PrintTreeNIZ(TREE* proot)
{
    if (proot == NULL)
        return;
    printf("\n Right Tree");
    iterPostorder(proot->right);
    printf("\n\n Left Tree");
    iterPostorder(proot->left);
    printf("\n\n Korin - %d", proot->viddal);
}


void OutputTreeStructure(const char* title)
{
    printf("\n\n\n Structur%s:\n\n", title);
    ShowLevels();
    ShowTree(root, 0);
    puts("\n");
}
#define TAB 7

void ShowTree(TREE* proot, int level)
{
    if (proot == NULL) return;
    ShowTree(proot->right, level + 1);
    printf("\n%*c%d", level * TAB + 10, ' ', proot->viddal);
    ShowTree(proot->left, level + 1);
}

void ShowLevels(void)
{
    int lev;
    printf(" Level: ");
    for (lev = 1; lev <= TreeHeight(root); lev++)
        printf(" %-*d", 6, lev);
    printf("\n\n");
}

int TreeHeight(TREE* proot)
{
    int lh, rh;
    if (proot == NULL) return 0;
    lh = TreeHeight(proot->left);
    rh = TreeHeight(proot->right);
    return lh > rh ? lh + 1 : rh + 1;
}


void EraseTree(TREE* proot)
{
    if (proot == NULL)
        return;
    EraseTree(proot->left);
    EraseTree(proot->right);
    free(proot);
}


STACK* createStack() {
    Stack* tmp = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    tmp->limit = STACK_INIT_SIZE;
    tmp->size = 0;
    tmp->data = (TREE**)malloc(tmp->limit * sizeof(TREE*));
    return tmp;
}

void freeStack(Stack** s) {
    free((*s)->data);
    free(*s);
    *s = NULL;
}

void push(Stack* s, TREE* item) {
    if (s->size >= s->limit) {
        s->limit *= 2;
        s->data = (TREE**)realloc(s->data, s->limit * sizeof(TREE*));
    }
    s->data[s->size++] = item;
}

TREE* pop(Stack* s) {
    if (s->size == 0) {
        exit(7);
    }
    s->size--;
    return s->data[s->size];
}

TREE* peek(Stack* s) {
    return s->data[s->size - 1];
}

void iterPostorder(TREE* root) {
    Stack* ps = createStack();
    TREE* lnp = NULL;
    TREE* peekn = NULL;

    while (!ps->size == 0 || root != NULL) {
        if (root) {
            push(ps, root);
            root = root->left;
        }
        else {
            peekn = peek(ps);
            if (peekn->right && lnp != peekn->right) {
                root = peekn->right;
            }
            else {
                pop(ps);
                printf("\n\t Visited -> %d", peekn->viddal);
                lnp = peekn;
            }
        }
    }

    freeStack(&ps);
}
//                                HELP WITH THAT
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void DeleteSomeNodes(void)
{
    printf("\n\t Deleting needing nods:\n");
    TREE* pfind = (TREE*)malloc(sizeof(TREE));

    do {
        if (pfind->z >= 7 && pfind->z <= 14) {
            DeleteNode(root);
            printf(" Number %d was deleted from tree\n", root);
        }
    } while (1);
    puts("\n\n");
}

#define NoSubTree 0
#define LeftSubTree -1
#define RightSubTree 1
#define TwoSubTrees 2

int DeleteNode(TREE* pnew_adr)
{
    TREE* proot = root;

    int subtr;
    if (proot == NULL) return 0;

    if (pnew_adr->viddal < proot->viddal)
        return DeleteNode(proot->left);

    if (pnew_adr->viddal > proot->viddal)
        return DeleteNode(proot->right);

    if (proot->left == NULL && proot->right == NULL)
        subtr = NoSubTree;
    else if (proot->left == NULL)
        subtr = RightSubTree;
    else if (proot->right == NULL)
        subtr = LeftSubTree;
    else
        subtr = TwoSubTrees;

    switch (subtr) {
    case NoSubTree:
        root = NULL; break;
    case LeftSubTree:
        root = proot->left; break;
    case RightSubTree:
        root = proot->right; break;
    case TwoSubTrees:
        TREE* pnew_root = proot->right, * pnew_prnt = proot;
        while (pnew_root->left != NULL) {
            pnew_prnt = pnew_root;
            pnew_root = pnew_root->left;
        }
        pnew_root->left = proot->left;
        if (pnew_root != proot->right) {
            pnew_prnt->left = pnew_root->right;
            pnew_root->right = proot->right;
        }
        root = pnew_root;
    }
    free(proot);
    return 1;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I don't understand point (2) what to bypass?

Comment: @kiner_shah, bypass the TREE using variant from the 2 point

Comment: You're meant to read the x, y and z coordinates from the file — why are you only storing the z coordinate?  You won't be able to print the input data accurately if you don't store it all.  However, that's probably amongst the least of your problems.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.